# change how solr stores date and time

Tags: postgresql, solr, timestamp

I have Solr 7.3.1 in my computers (both Windows and GNU/Linux machines), and it grabs data from a Postgres db. 
I have a timestap column in a table I need to index... my problem is Solr stores that date in UTC even if I've set SOLR_TIMEZIONE to CEST inside solr.in.sh

Let the date stored to the database be something like 2018-07-02 17:00:00.000 (CEST)

If I query my solr index, with db_field:[* TO 2018-07-02T17:00:00.000Z], I find 2018-07-02T15:00:00.000Z result, and not 17:00:00.000Z

Who can tell me why ? How is it possible to store the correct (with timestamp) information ?

I found the [working_with_dates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/working-with-dates.html) documentation page, and it seems solr can't work other than UTC. Is it correct ? How I'm I supposed to query it ? (I have a front end page which users search in local timezone... have I to subtract 1/2 hours every time ???

thanks a lot.

EDIT

I also tryed changing my db column to timestamptz, and re-indexing data... but nothing changed.
If I set SOLR_TIMEZONE parameters back to UTC, I have problems with delta-import queries..

Comment: Have you tried using TZ parameter in the query as per the page you linked? What happens when you do?

Comment: I've tryed, but I haven't managed to work. I obtain the same result when I query the index. this i my example query http://localhost:8983/solr/log_cd/select?TZ=Europe/Rome&q=*:* and one of the results is "date":"2018-07-02T10:28:39.979Z"... which is still in UTC and not CEST as expected

Comment: The date is stored and returned in UTC. But the conditions should have been recalculated to use TimeZone offsets.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the query ?